# How to Print specific row in each page Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-server

`whileprintingrecords;`
`global numbervar DetailCount;`

`DetailCount := DetailCount + 1;`

`Global numbervar DetailCount;`

`DetailCount Mod 10 = 0`

---

`IF Remainder (RecordNumber, 8) = 0 THEN`
 `TRUE`
`ELSE`
`FALSE`

### IF Remainder (RecordNumber, 8) = 0 and not OnLastRecord THEN
TRUE
ELSE
FALSE

i have try this codes but not get it.

Answer (score 0):

Please describe better what you would like to print on each page.
I'm guessing you would like to print a summary that would only show the sum of one printed page.

You need 3 formulas:

sum_pagesum (should be placed in the details-section as hidden field):

```
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar pagesum;
pagesum:= pagesum + {WHATEVER};
```

current_pagesum (should be placed in the page-footer-section, this prints your sum):

```
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar pagesum;
pagesum;
```

reset_pagesum (should be placed in the page-footer-section after the current_pagesum)

```
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar pagesum;
pagesum:= 0;
```